# Capture cmd error to file in CURRENT directory?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a PowerShell script that restarts servers listed in a file.

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    try {
        cmd /c "shutdown.exe /r /f /m \\$server /t 0 /d p:0:0 /c 'PlannedRestart'" 
        "$server`tRestarted"
        "$server`tRestarted" | Out-File -FilePath .\RestartServers_LOG.txt -Append
    } catch {
        "$server`t" + cmd /c ">&1"
        "$server`t" + cmd /c "dir > .\RestartServers_LOG.txt 2>&1"
    }
}
```

I am trying to catch any errors that may occur from the CMD to output on the PowerShell session as well as to a file in the CURRENT directory, so in PowerShell that would be `.\` but I don't know what the current directory specification is for CMD. Unless its the same thing?

Essentially, I am hoping to accomplish something similar to how we can capture the exception message of PowerShell like this:

```
"$server`t" + $_.Exception.Message.ToString().Split(":")[1].Replace("`n","") |
    Out-File -FilePath .\RestartServers_LOG.txt -Append
```

but CMD doesn't deal with exceptions like PowerShell, and instead STDERR.

Note: I am using the command `shutdown.exe` because PowerShell doesn't have ability to restart "planned" or "unplanned" unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it the PoSh way:

```
$params = '/r', '/f',
          '/t', '0',
          '/d', 'p:0:0',
          '/c', 'PlannedRestart'

$servers | ForEach-Object {
    $output = & shutdown.exe /m "\\${_}" @params 2>&1
    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        "{0}`tRestarted" -f $_
    } else {
        "{0}`tRestart failed:`t{1}" -f $_, $output
    }
} | Set-Content '.\RestartServers_LOG.txt'
```

External commands don't throw exceptions in the first place, so your `try..catch` wouldn't do anything anyway.

Comment: your absolutely right, the try catch was not working as intended it seems because it needs exceptions

Comment: i tried your script and its perfect! but how can i print to the console as well? it only prints to file

Comment: @Cataster `Set-Content` -> `Tee-Object`

Comment: do i pipe that? like Set-Content -> Tee-Object | Set-Content '.\RestartServers_LOG.txt'

Comment: No. You replace one cmdlet with the other. Please check the documentation for usage information.

Comment: i checked the documentation and tried this: Set-Content -> Tee-Object -FilePath '.\RestartServers_LOG.txt'. got error: Set-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FilePath'.

Comment: i tried Tee-Object without set-content and it worked. i guess you cant use them both

Comment: Technically you could do `| Tee-Object some_file | Set-Content other_file`, but that normally wouldn't make much sense, since it'd write the same output to 2 different files.

Comment: true true. btw, when it says "Restart failed:server:error" in the file, can i remove the server name form this message? i thought its _$ but when i removed that it gave some errors.

Comment: You man you want the failure message without the server name? Or not at all?

Comment: yes without server name. because the server name is already listed before this output status message. so why repeat it again right? for example, this is the output in the file i get: server1 Restart failed: server1:error.....

Comment: Change ``"{0}`tRestart failed:`t{1}" -f $_, $output`` to ``"Restart failed:`t{0}" -f $output`` (or just `$output` if you also don't want the leading "Restart failed").

Comment: so its gonna print like this: server1 Restart failed: error?

Comment: No. If you want output like that you'd need to leave the format string as it is and remove the server name from the beginning of `$output`. Please post a new question if you need help accomplishing that.